# Как вывести имена объектов из массива объектов?

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Изучаю PHP в свободное время и столкнулся с проблемой. Полагаюсь на вашу помощь.

Есть класс паттерна регистра, через него подключаются объекты, например:

```
$registry = Registry::singleton();
$registry->storeObject('db', 'db' );
```

Доступ к объекту осуществляется таким образом:

```
$database = $registry->getObject('db');
```

Объекты хранятся в массиве в самом регистре

```
private static $objects = array();
```

В каждом объекте есть метод возвращающий имя объекта, т.е.

```
print $database->getClassName();
```

выведет имя объекта - "объект базы данных".

Нужен метод, который выведет имена всех объектов из массива `$objects`

Пока имею:

```
public function getObjectsList()
{
    $names = array();
    for($i = 0; $i <= count(self::$objects)-1; $i++)
    {
         array_push($names, self::$objects[$i]->getClassName());
    }

    return $names;
}
```

но само собой получаю ошибку

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getClassName() on a non-object
>   in...

Собственно, как реализовать этот метод, чтоб на выходе получить значения возвращаемые методом `getClassName()` каждого объекта?

**РЕШЕНО**

`getObjectsList` принимает вид как показано ниже `Dmitriy Simushev`

вывод, например:

```
foreach ($registry->getObjectsList() as $names)
{
    echo '<li>' . $names . '</li>';
}
```

Comment: Внутри цикла посмотрите, что внутри $objects var_dump( self::$objects[$i] )

Comment: Вы неправильно обходите ассоциативнй массив объектов. В своем ответе я указал как нужно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В неправильно обходите массив объектов. Вместо обхода ассоциативного массива, вы пытаетесь обходить индексный массив.

Нужно как-то так:

```
public function getObjectsList()
{
    $names = array();
    foreach(self::$objects as $obj) {
        $names[] = $obj->getClassName();
    }

    return $names;
}
```